# Need help in table creation with constraints

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement in which I have to create,

1. a person table with person id, Fname, Lname attributes
   and also a person can be an employee or manager.
2. There is a constraint, a manager should be mapped to 1 or more emp (at least one emp).
3. Now, in this case, do we need to create a separate table for employee and manager and link it to person, if so how do we link both the table to person table and maintain the above-mentioned constraint

Note: There are no specific attributes for emp or manager table

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a *standard* Scott's EMP table (if you're familiar with it). Something like this:

- ID_EMP column is common to all persons
- ID_MGR shows who is that person's manager

---

```
SQL> create table person
  2    (id_emp number        constraint pk_pers primary key,
  3     fname  varchar2(20),
  4     lname  varchar2(20),
  5     id_mgr number        constraint fk_mgr_emp references person (id_emp)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into person (id_emp, fname, lname, id_mgr)
  2    select 1, 'Little' , 'Foot'    , null from dual union
  3    select 2, 'Charles', 'Leclerc' , 1    from dual union
  4    select 3, 'Rio'    , 'Haryanto', 1    from dual union
  5    select 4, 'Seb'    , 'Vettel'  , 2    from dual union
  6    select 5, 'Romain' , 'Grosjean', 2    from dual;

5 rows created.
```

Hierarchical view:

```
SQL> select lpad(' ', 2 * level) || lname employee
  2  from person
  3  start with id_mgr is null
  4  connect by prior id_emp = id_mgr;

EMPLOYEE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Foot
    Leclerc
      Vettel
      Grosjean
    Haryanto

SQL>
```